# Teradata SQL: Error 4566 - Query failing for me but working for coworkers

Tags: sql, teradata

I inherited a query from coworkers that works for them. I have the same database access and set up my ODBC driver in the same way, although am using Teradata vs. Query Chameleon to run the query. The difference is that every time I run my query, I am getting:

> SELECT Failed. 4566: Relation "<>" does not exist

Is there any way to fix this query?

(This is the simplest of the several queries that are all experiencing the same failure:)

```
SELECT CAST(DR.month_id AS INTEGER) AS DATE
    ,CAST(SUM(LD.Count) AS INTEGER) AS Count
    ,CAST(SUM(LD.revenue) AS FLOAT) AS Revenue 
    ,CAST(SUM(LD.revenue) / SUM(LD.Count)  AS FLOAT) AS AvgRevPerUnit 
    ,CAST(SUM(LD.Count) / SUM(LD.Count) AS FLOAT) AS AttachRate
FROM database1                  AS OS
INNER JOIN database2        AS LD ON (LD.id = OS.id)
INNER JOIN database3                    AS LT ON (LD.id = LT.id)
INNER JOIN database4            AS DR ON (LD.id = DR.id)
INNER JOIN database5    AS FS ON (LD.id = FS.id)
WHERE 0 = 0
    AND OS.desc IN ('Description I want')
    AND DR.year >= (YEAR(current_date) - 2)
    AND LT.desc = ('ABREV')
    AND FS.code NOT IN ('CANCELED')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Post your query?

Comment: Edit your question to include the query code. Do not place it in the comments.

Comment: There may be other problems but `desc` is a reserved word.

Comment: Ah, that was part of my editing to remove potentially sensitive field names. Should I change in question? (Thanks - my apologies - still newish here!)

Comment: Yes, change it in the question to be exactly what you are executing that produces the error.

Comment: There are lots of keywords (DATE, COUNT, LT, YEAR), but `YEAR(current_date)` is not valid Teradata SQL, depending on an ODBC setting it's automatically translated, try `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, dnoeth! I tried it but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Without the actual query it's impossible to help.

Comment: Access does some interesting things to SQL when passing it over to ODBC drivers. What version of the Teradata ODBC driver are you using? If it's a newer one (15.10 or 16) then you may need to switch on "Enable Legacy Parcer" in whatever DSN you are using. Are your coworkers using a different/older version?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, JNevill. I tried that (at your suggestion), but it's still giving me the "Relation database1 does not exist" error.

Comment: Can you try to execute this in SQL*Assistant directly?